# How to retrieve the window.localStorage.storedparameters?

Tags: html

I'm storing the values in window.localstorage.storedparameters. When i'm pulling back, i have some issues. So i would like to know where these data storing in the browser ? Is this storing data differ based on browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the chrome browser.

Just go to developer tools by pressing F12. And then go to "Resources" tab and then go to "Local storage" option. And you will see all your local storage of browser there.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve them programmatically using the `window.localStorage` object. To get a single item, either `localStorage.nameOfItem` or `localStorage.getItem('nameOfItem')` will work.